# DataWeave XML to POJO Transformation

Tags: xml, soap, mule, pojo, dataweave

I am trying to transform the result of an SOAP call to a set of POJO's -the following is an example of what my existing XML looks like and the transformation I am trying to apply.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
  <order>
   <StoreID />
   <Total>false</Total>
   <IndividualEntry>
     <Number>8</Number>
     <DeliverCharge>30.0</DeliverCharge>
   </IndividualEntry>
   <IndividualEntry>
     <Number>7</Number>
     <DeliverCharge>20.0</DeliverCharge>
   </IndividualEntry>
   <IndividualEntry>
     <Number>6</Number>
     <DeliverCharge>1.0</DeliverCharge>
   </IndividualEntry>
 </order>
```

My Data Weave Transformation is as follows - as per the documentation you need to use a multi-key selector for repeated keys(in this case IndividualEntry) but how do I end up implementing that for this scenario ?

```
Orders: payload.orders.*order map {
    StoreID : $.StoreID,
    Total   : $.Total,
    IndividualEntry: {
        Number: $.Number,
       DeliverCharge: $.DeliverCharge   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like below

```
Orders: payload.orders.*order map {
StoreID : $.StoreID,
Total   : $.Total,
IndividualEntry: $.*IndividualEntry map {
    Number: $.Number,
   DeliverCharge: $.DeliverCharge   
}
}
```